# Searching for value combination in two columns of a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, conditional-statements

I'm attempting to write a script to query a database for a combination of values using ruby on rails.  My aim is to find out the following: *Where `column1==x`, does `column2==y`?*

I had thought the following would do the trick but it seems not to.

```
MyValues.where(column1: x, column2: y)
```

Rather, it kicks out something like the following:

```
IdKey::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000004ae4d28
```

Any ideas where I might be going wrong and how I might go right?

As always, the help is much appreciated.

Comment: How does your listed query differ from your expected results? Please use examples.

Comment: simply run the OR query.

Comment: @ptd Very fair question, I've added the output above.

Comment: `M.where` returns a relation so that you can `M.where(...).where(...)` and such. If you want to access the result set from the query you'll have to say so: `M.where(...).first`, `M.where(...).each { |m| ... }`, etc.

Comment: @muistooshort I might be misunderstanding you but when I entered `MyValues.where(column1: x, column2: y).last`, it simply outputted the names of the columns `column 1 column 2` when the combination didn't exist and outputted something like `IdKey::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000004ae4d28` when they did exist.  (I suppose that's validation of a sort but is there any way we could boil it down to a true/false statement?)  :-)

Comment: Do you want a OR or AND query result?

Comment: @hkumar Hey, sorry for ignoring your suggestion.  I'm after an AND result.  If they're both there, I want a true if I have one without the other I want a false.

Comment: how about MyValues.where("column1 = ? && column2 = ?", x, y)

Comment: @hkumar What database is going to understand `&&` as a logical conjunction operator?

Comment: @muistooshort: what about MySQL

Comment: @hkumar I don't know, does it? That's certainly not standard SQL in any case.

Comment: @muistooshort: yes, it does. Just try it out today. :)

Comment: What if one row has x and y, but another row has x but not y? Keep in mind you are asking a single question on the entire table, not on each individual row (so it seems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only interested in existence then say so:

```
MyValues.where(column1: x, column2: y).exists?
# or
MyValues.exists?(column1: x, column2: y)
```

If you just say `MyValues.where(column1: x, column2: y)` then you're going to get a relation back so that you can add more conditions, ordering, etc. and a relation won't touch the database until you do something that requires it to.

Comment: FTW! I'd tried using `present?` but not `exists?`; as you can no doubt tell, I've got a bit to learn.  Many thanks!